# $(Configuration)と$(ConfigurationName)の違い

Tags: c, visual-studio

Visual Studioのマクロで$(Configuration)と$(ConfigurationName)がありますがこの違いは何でしょうか　同じものが入っているように見えます
どうやって使い分ければいいですか

Comment: 新規プロジェクトでも両方ありますか？[VS2008までは$(ConfigurationName)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/c02as0cs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)、[VS2010以降は$(Configuration)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/c02as0cs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)のみのようです。

Comment: 2010を使っています
「構成プロパティ」の「デバッグ」とかには$(ConfigurationName)はありませんでした　使用しても空になりました
「構成プロパティ」の「C/C++」とかには$(Configuration)と$(ConfigurationName)の両方がありました
$(ConfigurationName)が展開されると「Debug」とかに展開されました

Comment: 本当だ。気が付きませんでした。2010はインストールしていないのですが、2013と2015も同様でした。

Comment: 2008も調べてみましたが、$(Configuration)はどこにもありませんでした。2010以降の$(ConfigurationName)は2008以前との互換性のために用意されている、ということにしておこうと思います。

Answer (score 1):

[インクルードディレクトリと追加のインクルードディレクトリの違い](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/12419/4236)でも少し触れましたが、Visual Studio 2010からビルドシステムが変更されていますので、どのバージョンに関する質問なのかが重要になります。また2010以降は存在するとしても過去バージョンとの互換を目的としている場合もあります。

Comment: 2010を使用していますが、両方の設定がありました。
プロパティの場所によって、使用できるものが違うようでした。