# インクルードディレクトリと追加のインクルードディレクトリの違い

Tags: c, visual-studio

VisualStudioのプロパティでインクルードディレクトリの項目と追加のインクルードディレクトリの項目がありますが　これらの違いは何でしょうか
どちらを使用すればよいのでしょうか

Answer (score 6):

[Visual Studio 2010からビルドシステムがVCBuildからMSBuildへ変更](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ee862524(v=vs.100).aspx)されていてプロジェクトファイルもvcprojからvcxprojに変更されています。互換性のためもあり冗長な設定になっています。

`追加のインクルードディレクトリ`は従来からあるプロジェクト固有に設定するものです。

`インクルードディレクトリ`はVisual Studio 2008までは[ツール]-[オプション]の[プロジェクトおよびソリューション]-[VC++ディレクトリ]に含まれていた項目で、基本的にはプロジェクトに依存しないグローバルな設定を目的としています。Visual Studio 2010以降では[表示]-[その他のウィンドウ]-[プロパティマネージャー]でツリーの中から「Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user」のプロパティを開きそこで設定することでグローバルな設定ができます。（実のところこの項目を使用してプロジェクト固有の設定もできてしまうため区別しづらくなっています。）

---

上記のほかにソリューションエクスプローラーのプロジェクトのプロパティからも`インクルードディレクトリ`が設定できるとのコメントがありましたがそれこそ

> （実のところこの項目を使用してプロジェクト固有の設定もできてしまうため区別しづらくなっています。）

と書いたものであり、機能上、設定できますし使うことは可能ですが、本来の趣旨とは異なっているためその点を理解した上で使う・使わないの判断は各々の自由かと思います。

Comment: 「プロパティマネージャー」という設定もあるのですね。
質問のインクルードディレクトリは、「ソリューションエクスプローラ」からあるプロジェクトを選択し、右クリックして開いた「プロパティページ」の「構成プロパティ」の「VC++ディレクトリ」の設定です
これとは別に「プロパティマネージャ」の「Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user」も確認しましたが、それぞれ別に設定できるようでした。
これら３つの違いは何でしょうか
どちらを使用すればよいのでしょうか

Comment: 実際に確認してみました。
「インクルードディレクトリ」に設定したものは%INCLUDE%で参照できるようになるみたいでした。
「追加のインクルードディレクトリ」に設定したものは参照できませんでした
何らかの使い分けがあるのかもしれませんが使い分ける必要は今のところないのでどちらかに統一しておこうと思います